# Imported SVG does not fully show up in rendered view

Tags: svg

I brought in an SVG logo and have had almost no problems so far. However, I've gotten to a bit in the logo which has 3 letters. The one in the middle does not fully show up in rendered view. I can go into edit mode and I see the full letter, but I'm stuck as to how to convert it to mesh and make it render correctly. I've included some screenshots. Despite how wonky this letter looks, I can't change the shape at all. It has to be exact like the logo I'm working from.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @susu I'm not sure. I'll give it a go and see. I can't imagine this is the problem though because I don't see any overlapping paths.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I experimented some more and found something that seemed to work. What I did was open that logo in Illustrator and then export it using the asset export. For some reason, doing that instead of doing the Save As actions, fixed my issue. Maybe I had screwed something up in the original SVG export settings. So while I'm not sure this is the reason, it may help you if you come across this.

Comment: Most of the problems with SVG are overlapping, or intersecting paths.

Comment: If saving as Asset really solves the issue ... You are my GURU ;-) thanks for a tip.